# How to add data from select options to last selected text area?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two text area and one drop down(select option). If i select any data from select option that value need to be add into last selected text area. I did one script but if remove data from textarea and adding its not working

```js
var lastID;

$(function() {
  $("textarea").on("click", function() {
    lastID = $(this).attr("id");
  });
  
  $("#drp_dwn").change(function() {
    $("#" + lastID).append(this.value);
  }).add();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="drp_dwn">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="110">110</option>
  <option value="120" selected>120</option>
</select>

<textarea rows="4" cols="40" type="text" name="content" id="textArea1"></textarea>
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" type="text" name="content" id="textArea2"></textarea>
```

Comment: try changing the `click` to `focusout`

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by `if remove data from textarea and adding its not working`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
$("#" + lastID).append(this.value);
```

Write this one

```
$("#" + lastID).val($("#" + lastID).val()+this.value);
```

As append doesn't change the value of the textarea, it adds to the html

Comment: I don't think that's the problem in the question.

Comment: It is exactly what the problem is, and that's what solved it. Try testing it.

Comment: its working but same value i cant able to add from dropdown. I mean if i add '10' and again i want to add '10' - its not working

Comment: I don't know if a dropdown is the right tool for this. What I would do is that I would put an empty option first, ("Select a Value"), and whenever the user selects a value, let's say 10, by jQuery we would reset the selected value to ("Select a Value")

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var lastID;

$(function() {
  $("textarea").on("blur", function() {
    lastID = $(this).attr("id");
  });
  
  $("#drp_dwn").change(function() {
    $("#" + lastID).val($("#" + lastID).val()+this.value);
  }).add();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="drp_dwn">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="110">110</option>
  <option value="120" selected>120</option>
</select>

<textarea rows="4" cols="40" type="text" name="content" id="textArea1"></textarea>
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" type="text" name="content" id="textArea2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Its working fine. thank you i have one more doubt on this.
Instead i using id i want to use as class name like: lastID = $(this).attr("class"); in this case how can i get multiple class without space (.classname1.classname2)

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly?? What do you mean by without space?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work:**

**step1 :**
You need to get the focused textarea value

```
var value = $("#" + lastID).val();
```

**step2 :**
adding new selected value

```
$("#" + lastID).val(value+this.value);
```

**Working Code:**

```
var lastID;
$(function() {
    $("textarea").on("focus", function() {
        lastID = $(this).attr("id");
    });
    $("#drp_dwn").change(function () { alert(1);
    var value = $("#" + lastID).val();
    $("#" + lastID).val(value+this.value);
    }).add();
});
```